# How do you properly set up a dotnet core class libray to publish to NuGet feed in Azure DevOps?

Tags: .net, .net-core, azure-devops

I created a test project to publish to my NuGet feed (in Artifacts), but I get an error in the dotnet push step. I used the classid editor and the default steps in the dotnet core template and added a new dotnet core step with the `nuget push` command. I get this error message:

No packages matched the search pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seemed to be the versions of the .netstandard SDK the project was referencing. I updated everything from 2.0 to 2.2 and the dotnet pack command works now.

Answer (score 0):

> How do you properly set up a dotnet core class libray to publish to NuGet feed in Azure DevOps?

When you got this error "*No packages matched the search pattern*", that means the `nuget push` task not got the nuget package file. May be that the package is not generated or the path to NuGet package(s) to publish is not correct.

So, to resolve this issue, first, we need make sure we have generate that nuget package. To generate the package, we need add a nuget `pack task` in the pipeline or add following property in the project file .csproj:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
  </PropertyGroup
```

We could check if that package is generated from the build log or using `copy` and `publish build artifacts` task.

If the packages is generated, we need to check if the path to NuGet package(s) to publish is correct, I set it as `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.nupkg`, and it works fine:

[image]

[image]

Note: If you are using nuget pack task to generate the package, the the path to NuGet package(s) to publish should be the path for Package folder in the nuget pack task.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have a dotnet pack step before this one. I've determined that it has something to do with the target framework being netstandard2.0. I was able to get it to work correctly with a netcoreapp2.1 project. When I pack the netstandard2.0 project it puts the assembly in a bin folder along with all the dependencies and I get this error:

C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.104\Sdks\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack\build\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.targets(202,5): error NU5026: The file 'D:\a\1\s\Shared\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\Shared.dll' to be packed was not found on disk. [D:\a\1\s\Shared\Shared.csproj]